# Game of life neighbor issue. array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I am working on the game of life program and I ran into a problem.

As you can see below, I am trying to count the number of neighbors.

The problem is that when it comes to counting the number of neighbors of co-ordinates that sit on the border of the set grid gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

To fix this, I used try and catch.

Only problem is that as soon as the the compiler detects an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, it passes straight to the catch part, not going through the other if statements.

Is there any way around this?

```
public int neighbours(int x, int y) {
    int result = 0;

    try {
        if (life[y + 1][x - 1] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y + 1][x] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y + 1][x + 1] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y][x + 1] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y][x + 1] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y - 1][x] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y - 1][x - 1] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
        if (life[y][x - 1] == '*') {
            result++;
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the `try-something-I-Know-Is-Bad` pattern. I would check for overflows **first** and take appropriate action

Comment: `life[y][x + 1]` is getting checked twice and `life[y - 1][x + 1]` is never checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a separate `try`/`catch` around every test to avoid skipping the rest when one of them raises an exception, but a better option is to check the values against bounds of the array beforehand. Or you could make the array have an unused extra row or column on every edge, then no check of the actually used cells would ever go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Way lot easier to maintain and less duplicate code!

```
public int neighbours(int x, int y) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=x-1; i<=x+1;i++){
        if(i<life.length && i>0){
            for(int j=y-1; j<=y+1;j++){
                if(j<life[i].length && j>0){
                    if (life[i][j] == '*') {
                        result++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tested your code? For cell (0,0), you already have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :)

Comment: Valid point, I forgot the negative check. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Improving Hache's code:

```
public int neighbours(int x, int y) {
    int result = 0;

    for(int i=x-1; i<=x+1;i++){
        //include border cell, so i>=0
        if(i<life.length && i>=0){
            for(int j=y-1; j<=y+1;j++){
                //again, include border cell, so j>=0
                if(j<life[i].length && j>=0){
                    //and to compare strings, please use equals()
                    if (life[i][j].equals("*")) {
                        result++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //don't count the cell itself
    return result - 1;
}
```